# Get only actually visible part of text value from a narrow input (get input "scroll")

Tags: javascript, html

I have a narrow `<input type="text">`, with text not "fitting" in the input field.

How do I get only the user-visible text range?

Example 1:

`An example of long input text
[An exam]`

The full text is "This is an example of long input text", however the input is only 7 characters wide, and the cursor is at the beginning, so only "An exam" fits into the input, and this is the text I want to get.

Example 2:

`An example of long input text
              [long in]`

The same text, but an user moved the cursor forward, so I want to get "long in"

Comment: *How do I get only the user-visible text range?* You can't. All you can do is extract the correct amount of characters based on the size of the `input` and the font size.

Comment: You will need to account for what font is being used, the font size (how many pixels a certain letter takes), and the input width, which to me sounds like a mild headache with no benefits.

Comment: Ohhhh, I've just realized that `scrollLeft` gives me actual scroll on the input. 

My font is monospace so all characters have the same width. I guess if I have `scrollLeft` and `clientWidth` then I have visible range in pixels. All I need to do is to recompute pixels to character.

Thanks folks.

Comment: As a side note, how do you plan on getting the value of the input, because when it loses focus it scrolls back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the font will always be `monospace`, To know the width of one character we can use the following.

```js
let charWidth = document.querySelector('.monospaceCharWidthCheck').getBoundingClientRect().width;
console.log(charWidth)
```

```css
span {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<span class="monospaceCharWidthCheck">a</span>
```

if the width of the input is dynamic, to know how many letters it can fit we just divide it's width by the character width, then `Math.round()` to get rid of the decimal point.

```js
let charWidth = document.querySelector('.monospaceCharWidthCheck').getBoundingClientRect().width;
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let inputlettersCapacity = Math.round(input.clientWidth / charWidth);
console.log('How many letters this input can fit visibly : ' + inputlettersCapacity)
document.querySelector('input[type=button]').onclick = (e) => {
  let visibleText;
  if (input.value.length > inputlettersCapacity)
    visibleText = input.value.substring(0, inputlettersCapacity);
  else
    visibleText = input.value;
  console.log(visibleText)
}
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  /* 16px to accommodate for the blinking cursor */
  font-size: 16px;
}

span {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  /* Which means we should add it here */
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<span class="monospaceCharWidthCheck">a</span>
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="get visible text">
```

partially visible characters, ignore them or count them, i'll leave that to you.

to get the visible value, i used a button click, clicking on the button makes the input loses focus which scroll the text to the beginning which is convenient for using `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of hard code it based on the assumed characters the specific width of the input field can fit.
In this case, it is `An exam` = 7 ( including whitespace ).

So, assuming the width of the input is dynamic and not static, you would have to know how many characters can fit in the certain width.

A way to do this ( in this case ) would be to get the first 7 characters of the input field like so:

```
var inputText = document.getElementById('myInputId').innerText;
var visibleCharacters = inputText.substring(0, 8);
```

EDIT:

Based on your "Example 2", in case you need to know where the cursor is, so that you get the substring from there on, like this:

```
var inputElem = document.getElementById('myInputId');
var inputText = inputElem.innerText;
var cursorIndex inputElem.selectionStart;
var visibleCharacters = inputText.substring(cursorIndex, cursorIndex + 7);

// You are getting the text from cursor point to +7 of that position ( in this case )
```

Of course, this is neither THE way to do it, nor the most accurate way either.
It's just a hack that I just came up with.